# Is search on index with less verity faster?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 3 index column on it lets saye `col1, col2, col3` they are all int

My friend said that, if column2 has less verity of data (I mean it has only 12,13,14 and other column have like random numbers), it is faster to put your condition for the `WHERE` clause on that column first, because mysql will begin to get populate data from that point first!

so basically he says that the second is faster

- `select * from my_table where col1=1 and col2=2 and col3=3`
- `select * from my_table where col2=2 and col1=1 and col3=3`

is that true? I couldn't find any reading material on the subject.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While "verity" is a term applied to datasets, it has nothing to do with databases. I think you are talking about cardinality.

The order in which you declare predicates in your query has **no impact at all** on how the optimiser resolves the query. You can easily test this yourself using 'explain'.

The order of columns in an index **does** have a big impact on performance